# Log4j Json Template Layout Config

Tags: http, logging, log4j, appender, jsontemplate

I am new to log4j logging and I have a scenario where I want to configure log4j to send http post request using JSON template layout for specific body structure. Below is the body format which is required for http request.

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "stream": {
                "label": "data"
            },
            "values": [
                [
                    "unix epoch till nano second", "strigified json log"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I configure it using log4j with json template layout?
Also any good references for better understanding log4j and Json template layout apart from official docs?
TIA !

Basic log4j configuration and sample json template layout for provided json object

Answer (score 0):

Add the log4j dependency to your project. If you are using Maven, add the following to your pom.xml:

```js
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's a sample log4j.properties configuration file:

```js
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, HTTP_POST

log4j.appender.HTTP_POST=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.HTTP_POST.Port=8080
log4j.appender.HTTP_POST.RemoteHost=example.com
log4j.appender.HTTP_POST.ReconnectionDelay=5000
log4j.appender.HTTP_POST.layout=org.apache.log4j.net.JSONLayout
```

Comment: Hi @hamzaouni, I get the log4j config but what I really dont understand is how can I create JSONLayout template which I'll be passing for above specified JSON  object